# Yii2: Setasign fpdi

Tags: pdf, yii2, fpdi

I am creating an application and used fpdi for the printable documents. But when I ran the code, it returned an error: **[image]setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\PdfParserException** . What are the possible causes of this error?

Comment: that means that the parser thinks that the file you have provided is invalid you might try some other file

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the code, parser tries to find PDF keyword in the file header. But does not find.

PDF file is corrupted or empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
```

Add this line to your code.